# How to use properties of an object literal without being inside a function in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, object-literal

I created an object literal in JS, but wanna to access a property without being in a function. Whenever I try, I don't get any results or it returns `null`.

JS:

```
var settings = {
        prev: '#prev',
        next: '#next',
        slides: '#slides',
        crslContainer: '#carousel',

        //I'm trying to access the 'slides' by using 'this.slides'
        inDent: $(this.slides).find('li').outerWidth(),
        fx: 'rotate',

        myFunction: function () {
          console.log(settings.inDent); //This shows null in the console, why??
        }
    }
```

In the code above I'm trying to access `slides` by using `this.slides`, all inside the same object, but the console says `null`. But when I do the method, `inDent: $('#slides').find('li').outerWidth()`, then it works. Why is that? I assumed it's the same as using those properties inside a function by using `this` keyword, apparently it's not the case.
I just wanna pass the value of that object property , i.e. a string, to another property that's not a function.

Many thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't refer to the "object being defined" in an object literal. That is, there's no way to have the value expression for a property of the under-construction object refer to the object itself in order to access another (presumably, already-defined) property.

You can however *add* a property to the object after it's been defined.

```
 var obj = { a: 0 };
 obj.b = (obj.a ? 1 : 2);
```

Or in your case:

```
 var settings = { ... };
 settings.inDent = ($(settings.slides).find('li').outerWidth());
```

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. your method works. They should have made object literals a bit more flexible, so we can transfer variables anywhere we want like constructors but nothing is perfect in life... lol. thanks though

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

```
this.inDent
```

The `inDent` field would be accessed via `settings.inDent` only outside of the `settings` object definition

Comment: Many thanks for your answer @scibuff. I know I can use  this.inDent but I can only do that inside a function.

Comment: This does not answer the question as they can't successfully use `this` or `this.inDent` inside the static declaration of the `settings` object.

Comment: @jfriend00 of course you can use `this` just try it - `var s = { x: 'foo', y:function(){ console.log(this.x); }}; s.y(); // outputs 'foo'`

Comment: @scibuff - that's inside a function.  That's explicitly NOT what the OP is asking about.  The OP is asking about the line they have like this: `inDent: $(this.slides).find('li').outerWidth(),` where one static declaration refers to another which is not possible.

Comment: @scibuff: What you've just demonstrate with the `console.log`, I know about that already, i.e. using `this` inside a function. But I wanna be able to use `this` when I'm declaring variables. I know I can use `this` when inside a function but my question is what about using `this` like that: `var obj = { foo: '#id', bar: $(this.foo) };` here I want `foo` value inside `bar`, that's my question but the answer is we cannot do tis techniques in object literals. But still thanks for your effort, I appreciate very much. I'm still learning...

Comment: @Shaoz, sorry I think I misunderstood your question originally - but you can still do what you wanna do - read my answer above (about closures)

Answer (score 0):

Use closures, e.g

```
var settings = function(){
    var private = {};
    private.slides = '#slides';

    var public = {}
    public.inDent = ($(private.slides).find('li').outerWidth());
    public.doSomething = function(){
        console.log( public.inDent );
    }

    return public;
}();
```

The advantage of this is also that it gives you "encapsulation" for free

BTW, you shouldn't rely on anything that is publicly available, because, well, it can be changed, e.g. `settings.inDent = null` and then `settings.doSomething()` may no longer function correctly. What correct way to do it is the following

```
...
private.inDent = ($(settings.slides).find('li').outerWidth());

public.inDent = private.inDent;
public.doSomething = function(){
    console.log( private.inDent );
}
```

i.e. make the `inDent` value "read only" (in a sense that nothing outside of the `settings` object can actually change the internal implementation of `private.inDent`); as long as you always use `private.inDent` from within `settings` you're safe because even if someone does `settings.inDent = null`, the `settings.doSomething();` will still function properly