# Javascript + Basic Object Literal Scope Issue

Tags: javascript, object-literal

I know this is very basic, but why does x return undefined in this code block?  Is there a way to define a property and immediately use it to set another property?

```
    var grid = {
        x : 75,
        y : 75,
        location : [grid.x, grid.y],                
        init : function () {
            console.log(grid.location[0]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: if you need to support IE8 or < then you can do something like: `location: function() { return [this.x, this.y] },`. same for init. Then to call it outside of grid, you use `grid.location()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use the variable to access properties of the object before the object has been assigned to the variable. While the object is created, the variable `grid` is still undefined. While the object is being created, you don't have any reference to it.

You can use the properies once the object has been assigned to the variable:

```
var grid = {
    x : 75,
    y : 75,
    init : function () {
        console.log(grid.location[0]);
    }
}

grid.location = [grid.x, grid.y];
```

You can also wrap this in a function expression to get code that returns the complete object:

```
var grid =
  (function(){

    var obj = {
      x : 75,
      y : 75,
      init : function () {
        console.log(grid.location[0]);
      }
    };
    obj.location = [obj.x, obj.y];

    return obj;

  })();
```

Comment: In your first example, why don't you put `this.location = [this.x, this.y];` into the `.init()` method instead of calling it manually from outside the object?

Comment: @insertusernamehere: That's one option, but it would only work if the `location` property is only accessed inside the `init` method, or only accessed after `init` has been called. Also it would reassign the property if `init` was called more than once, and that might not be desirable.

Comment: True that. I thought that there was some other magic I'm overlooking. :) In this case I think that the `.init()`-method will act like some sort of constructor and will be called only once.

Comment: @Guffa: I set my location array inside the init function as it's only accessed after init has been called.  Big ups to all these great responses.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to define a property and immediately use it to set another property?

[No.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9873893/139010) However, you can [use a getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/get), which is more-or-less syntactic sugar for a function:

```
var grid = {
    x : 75,
    y : 75,
    get location() {
        return [this.x, this.y];
    },                
    init : function () {
        console.log(grid.location[0]);
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/erUJj

This answer sums up the various options: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15486618

Comment: Note: This is not supported in IE8.

Comment: @JeffShaver I strongly advise that you read the documentation linked in my answer. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/get

Comment: @MattBall however, according to your linked documentation, this isn't compatible with IE until version 9 as Guffa said.

Comment: @JeffShaver that's true. My linked answer and Guffa's comment both said as much.

Comment: Note also that this changes the behaviour, as the property returns a new array with the current values each time it's used, instead of assigning a copy of the values when the object is created.